# TomEE, EJB and virtual-hosts

Tags: ejb, virtualhost, openejb, apache-tomee

I am simulating multiple TomEE (1.7.1) instances using virtual-hosts.
I have multiple virtual-hosts that are deploying the same war with the same EJBs.

This leads to:

```
org.apache.openejb.DuplicateDeploymentIdException: Application cannot be deployed as it contains deployment-ids which are in use
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

did you try openejb.deploymentId.format = {appId}/{ejbJarId}/{ejbName} in conf/system.properties?

To make it even more portable coming 1.7.2 (release process in progress) and coming 2.x will support:

openejb.deploymentId.format = {host}/{appId}/{ejbJarId}/{ejbName}

and even

openejb.deploymentId.format = {hash}/{host}/{appId}/{ejbJarId}/{ejbName}

Comment: since it's the exact same war, this id is not unique. Unless there's some way to add the host to the template, I'll have to wait to the next release... :)